# Impossible to export photo embedded in artboard in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, raster

I am trying to export several illustrations spread on 6 **Artboards** of different sizes (composite of vectors and raster images) for web ads in Illustrator CC 2019 v.23.

Whenever I export my **artboards** (and however I do it, Export for Screens or Save for Web alike), the photo part of the illustration exports very badly:

[image]

I've tried exporting at 4x and then scaling down but even then I have a similar problem:

[image]

In the **Artboard**, the photo looks fine (source image is 5k x 4k pixels, and the problems happens with a 1800px version of the image too):

[image]

Setting are set as such:

[image]

At this point I'm so frustrated and angry at Illustrator's countless bugs that I'm close to just make a screenshot and call it a day.
Unless if I'm missing something super obvious... **Am I doing anything wrong?**

Comment: We need a few more details of the export configuration you’re using to answer intelligently - perhaps a screen cap of your export settings and / or description of intent / use case could help? So for example, we don’t know if you’re exporting `.svg` or  `.png` or `.pdf`... if you’ve defined slices or just art boards - you get the idea - help us help you!

Comment: @GerardFalla See my edit

Comment: My rule of thumb - ratios... if the final output is raster and 50% or more of the visuals are raster.. then do it in Photoshop. If you need vector elements, copy/paste from AI to PS or create those natively in Photoshop. I can't say for *certain* what the issue is.. but I do wonder, are you rotating the raster image in Illustrator? It appears so.. AI does **not** interpolate pixels - so rotating rasters = degradation. There is **zero** edge anti-aliasing or interpolation in AI for placed raster images. Rotate in Photoshop and place the *pre-rotated* image in AI. You *might* get better results.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand - in my illustration a vector hand is holding the photo (finger layers in front and behind the photo). How would I do that in Ps?

Comment: You might not be able to.. realize I can't see the entire piece. But realistically, there's not a whole lot you can do in AI that can't be done in PS. It may take a few vector layers in PS, but there's rarely an "impossibility" with regards to stacking order/masks/layering. In any event, the photo rotation is probably the issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the legacy export, it exposes better antialiasing options. In either case your image is a bit unoptimally sized for the task at hand. Anyway i find that adobe is very good at adding features that are useless because the later implmentors botched something. ALL in all illsutrator works very well if you choose to use the oldest possible toolset for each task, with about 4 exceptions.

Comment: Why embed? Try to not embed this photo and use AI's linking instead. Otherwise just paste the vector part from AI into PS, add the photo via PS and do this banner in PS.

Comment: @Lucian how is linking and embedding different? It's mostly a vector illustration with moving parts (vector fingers holding a photo), so bringing the vector parts into PS makes no logical sense. joojaa's comment worked (legacy export). The "Export for screens" botches non-vector elements in AI comps - one more thing AI does wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Let’s start simple: `.png` 8 bit depth is a lovely format, but has the same 256 colour limitations as a bunch of lossy formats: it therefore handles out of gamut colours via dithering, which looks like bad anti-aliasing - I think that is part of your issue here.

Comment: I disagree, the photo should look dithered, eventually with less colors, but definitely not distorted. It could be black and white or even two-tone and the lines behind the two people in the photo would still look straight. [Here's a 16 color GIF of the 1st screenshot for you to compare.](https://imgur.com/a/jBLqDDq)